# Отображение изображения в html странице при верстке посредством python

Tags: python, html

Такой вопрос, познаю flask и python.
Взяла за основу шаблон с bootstrap, в html коде нет изображений, решила добавить от себя и
столкнулась с проблемами, изображение не отображается.
Пробовала следующим образом:

```
    <div class="p-4 p-md-5 mb-4 text-white rounded bg-dark">
    <div class="col-md-6 px-0">
        <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic">Title of a longer featured blog pos</h1>
        <p class="lead my-3">Multiple lines of text that form the lede, informing new readers quickly and efficiently about what’s most interesting in this post’s contents.</p>
        <p><img src="images\photo1.jpg"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Создала папку в проекте - images, в нее добавила изображение photo1.jpg.
Использовала pycharm в качестве среды.
Подскажите, как правильно в таком случае вывести изображение на странице?

Comment: `"images/photo1.jpg"` может так? `"/images/photo1.jpg"` или так...

Comment: Как вы сохраняете изображения? или вы просто пытаетесь вытащить из папки?

Answer (score 1):

Разобралась в чем проблема. папку images нужно было не просто создать в папке проекта, а создать папку static (она у меня была создана под файлы css) и там уже создать папку images поместив в нее изображение. По итогу код в html файле, где необходимо отобразить изображение выглядит так:

```
<p><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/photo1.jpg') }}"></p>
```